# Spring tool suite doesn't load changes on the fly with html files

Tags: java, spring, spring-tool-suite

Whenever i modify any html file in my spring mvc project, i have to stop and run it again so i can see the changes i've made. Is there a way to configure my STS to enable this feature? I've seen people saying to enable the 'Build Automatically' option under 'Project', but it doesn't work.

I'm using the latest release: 3.7.2

Comment: How are you building the project? With Maven? Gradle?

Comment: I think there are a bunch of deploy settings available on the servers editor page (double click on the server in the servers view). There should be an action to automatically redeploy the app when something changes.

Comment: In addition to that, if you are using Spring Boot (which I highly recommend), you could also take a look at the Spring Boot Devtools. They allow you to do even more without restarting or redeploying the app. Highly highly recommend!!!

Answer (score 0):

The Sprint Tool Suite is just an Editor ,For the HTML/JS/CSS or any FrontEnd Code to reflect the mutation you have to go through the process of installing GRUNT or GULP .
Install GRUNT/GULP (I would suggest GULP) 
Write some code in the GULP file.js and enable autoreload and bunch of other node plugins and your work will be done .

cheers